# Remove empty item before "Fn::join" in Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want create a string with `Fn::Join` from a list of parameters, but I don't know how to ignore the empty one.

**How can I ignore an empty parameter to have "application-dev" instead of "application---dev" ?**

For example, my parameters are:

```
Parameters:
  AppName:
    Description: "Application name:"
    Type: String
    Default: "application"

  AppType:
    Description: "Application type:"
    Type: String
    Default: "" <----------------------------- This one can be empty !

  AppEnv:
    Description: "Application environment:"
    Type: String
    Default: "dev"
```

In my ressources, I try:

```
Resources:
  S3BucketTest:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub '${AppName}-${AppType}-${AppEnv}'
      Tags: 
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: !Join ['-', [!Ref AppName, !Ref AppType, !Ref AppEnv]]
```

Btw, the `BucketName` is "application--dev"...
And the `Tag Name` is "application--dev"...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `!If` and `!Equals`:

```
Resources:
  S3BucketTest:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    Properties:
      BucketName: !If [!Equals ["", !Ref AppType], !Sub '${AppName}-${AppEnv}', !Sub '${AppName}-${AppType}-${AppEnv}']
      Tags: 
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: !If [!Equals ["", !Ref AppType], !Join ['-', [!Ref AppName, !Ref AppEnv], !Join ['-', [!Ref AppName, !Ref AppType, !Ref AppEnv]]
```

Comment: I'm working on your solution. It's a little more complicated if I want to handle other field as empty string. But I think your approach is a good start. Tk

Comment: @Akarun the other solution would be to use a `Condition`, and then leverage the condition to determine whether to create a resource or not, but that would require you having two resources that are almost identical in the template (for each resource you need this behavior for). The solution I provided is better

Comment: I'm agreeing your solution. Just trying to found a more flexible/concise syntax to generate the string (using the "!If" approach you gave me)